# AND multiple values of a filter in sphinx

Tags: php, search-engine, sphinx

I have an attribute in my sphinx index tag_id and now I want to fetch all record that have tag_id 10 and 11

When I do $sphinxClient->setFilter('tag_id', array(10,11)) it fetches all have tag_id 10 or 11
Is it possible to AND both values rather than OR?

Answer (score 1):

```
$sphinxClient->setFilter('tag_id', array(10));
$sphinxClient->setFilter('tag_id', array(11));
```

Multiple calls to setFilter are ANDed :)

Comment: I did the same but setting same filter (tag_id) with different values is not working

Comment: Well it works for me. You might have something else wrong. tag_id is a MVA isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Why would two different values return result with AND??

It's like

WHERE id = 1 AND id = 2

WHICH will never be possible.
Can you tell us the scenerio you're trying to work at?

Comment: With Sphinx, if your attribute is MVA (multi-valued attributes) this kind of condition can return rows : `WHERE tag_id = 1 AND tag_id = 2`

Answer (score 0):

In my case Barry's answer didn't worked.

I have check what im filtering - an array or not array. By specification http://php.net/manual/en/sphinxclient.setfilter.php for values you need: 'Plain array of integer values.'

```
if( !empty( $filters['user_id'] ) ) 
{
  if( is_array( $filters['user_id'] ) )
  {
    $this->sphinx->setFilter( 'user_id', $filters['user_id'] );
  }
  else
  {
    $this->sphinx->setFilter( 'user_id', array( (int) $filters['user_id'] ) );
  }
}
```